TypeScript Error: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | ObjectId'
I feel like this issue is simple to resolve. However, for the life of me I cannot come up with a resolution for this error.
folderSchema.ts:
import mongoose, { Document, Schema, model } from "mongoose";

export interface IFolder extends Document {
  name: string;
  owner: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
  parent: mongoose.Types.ObjectId | null;
  files: mongoose.Types.ObjectId[];
  subfolders: mongoose.Types.ObjectId[];
  sharedWith: mongoose.Types.ObjectId[];
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
}

const folderSchema = new Schema<IFolder>(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
    parent: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Folder", default: null },
    files: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "File" }],
    subfolders: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Folder" }],
    sharedWith: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);

export default model<IFolder>("Folder", folderSchema);


index.ts:
export { default as Folder } from "./folderSchema.ts";

folderController.ts:
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { Folder } from "./index.ts";

//Delete a folder
export const deleteFolder = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const folder = await Folder.findOne({
      _id: req.params.id,
      owner: req.user?.userId,
    });

    if (!folder) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Folder not found" });
    }

    //Using recursion to delete the folders and files within parent folder.
    await recursiveDelete(folder._id); //Line causing error.

    res.json({ message: "Folder and contents deleted successfully" });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error deleting folder" });
  }
};

//Recursive function to delete
async function recursiveDelete(folderId: string | mongoose.Types.ObjectId) {
  const folder = await Folder.findById(folderId);

  if (!folder) {
    return;
  }

  //Delete all files in this folder
  await File.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: folder.files } });

  for (let subfolderId of folder.subfolders) {
    await recursiveDelete(subfolderId);
  }

  await Folder.findByIdAndDelete(folderId);
}

What could be the problem?
I've tried to use the .lean() to get plain JS Object, then I typed it as "IFolder | null". I've also tried a custom type guard.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] that imports/includes/declares anything you need for others to see what you're seeing in their own IDEs (i.e., reproducible). (For example, what's Folder?) Preferably you'd also remove things you don't need (i.e., minimal).

Is ../schemas/index.ts something we need? Like, this single-file playground link looks closer but it's still missing File and apparently request doesn't have the properties you think they do? The goal of a [mre] is to get people quickly up to speed so they can focus on the problem you're having, instead of needing to work on setup.

I believe you need to track where Folder is originating from. I've made the corrections. Sorry for the lack of context and any confusion—this is my first post here.

I still see lots of errors you're not asking about, as you can see in this playground link. If you can [edit] to put a [mre] in a single file suitable for pasting into an IDE, I'll take another look. Otherwise I'll just disengage, since I have yet to be able to reproduce the issue. Good luck!

Hm, I'm reviewing the playground link, and I noticed that the properties 'status', 'json', and 'deleteMany' (from Mongoose) are used in the code. Since the code is connected to MongoDB through Mongoose, these properties should exist and function as intended. However, I see an 'unknown' error in the playground, which is the type of issue I'm encountering.

Until I see the other errors gone I don't know what to say about the error you're asking about. A [mre] shouldn't have extraneous problems. The _id property seems to be implicitly any because of errors with params, and that complicates the issue with the line you are asking about. I'm no mongoose/mongodb expert and since I still have no [mre] I think I'll just disengage. Hopefully someone who knows what's going on here will come along.

Ah, I'll try to hone this down into a minimal reproducible example. I really do appreciate your time and help.

I've found and resolved the issue again thanks.
